# Calculate ROIC using Alpha Vantage API

Tags: python, alpha-vantage

I am attempting to calculate Return on Invested Capital using [Alpha Vantage API](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/). **Can anyone help me validate the code below?**

### Other sources

I am not sure I get the proper result, as I can't even find 2 stock analysis websites to agree on the values.

| Source | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Morning star: DAVA](http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=DAVA&region=usa&culture=en-US) | 35.34 | 27.77 | 23.38 | 18.70 | 8.77 |
| [MSN: DAVA](https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/analysis/nys-dava/fi-bjmnww) |  |  |  |  | 9.90 |
| [GuruFocus: DAVA](https://www.gurufocus.com/term/ROIC/DAVA/ROIC-Percentage/Endava) | 28.57 | 26.01 | 20.76 | 23.07 | 11.86 |
| [Rule 1 investing: DAVA](https://toolbox.ruleoneinvesting.com/members/finance/default.aspx?stock=DAVA) | 56.0 | 34.5 | 27.3 | 14.4 | 9.1 |
| Below algorithm results (a bit far from the others) | 53.65 | 36.70 | 28.16 | 15.80 | 7.84 |

### Formula

ROIC = Net Operating Profit after Tax / (Total equity + total Interest Bearing Debt)

1. Calculate NOPAT (calculate tax rate and multiply with operating income)
2. Calculate Invested Capital
3. Calculate ROIC

### Alpha Vantage response attributes

Get [balance sheet (from alpha vantage)](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BALANCE_SHEET&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo). I got "totalShareholderEquity" and "currentDebt" from here.

Get [income statement](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=INCOME_STATEMENT&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo). I calculated **NOPAT = "operatingIncome" * (1 - "incomeTaxExpense" / "incomeBeforeTax")**

#### Code

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

ALPHA_KEY = '________'
symbol = 'DAVA'

def request_function(func: str, symbol: str, key: str):
    url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function={func.upper()}&symbol={symbol.upper()}&apikey={key.upper()}'
    response = requests.request("GET", url)
    return response.json()

data_income_statement = request_function('income_statement', symbol, ALPHA_KEY)
data_balance_sheet = request_function('balance_sheet', symbol, ALPHA_KEY)

## Income statement
# tax rate = "incomeTaxExpense" / "incomeBeforeTax"
# NOPAT = "operatingIncome" * (1 - tax rate)
# NOPAT = "operatingIncome" * (1 - "incomeTaxExpense" / "incomeBeforeTax")

inc_stmt = pd.json_normalize(data_income_statement['annualReports'])

inc_stmt['operatingIncome'] = pd.to_numeric(inc_stmt['operatingIncome'], downcast="float")
inc_stmt['incomeTaxExpense'] = pd.to_numeric(inc_stmt['incomeTaxExpense'], downcast="float")
inc_stmt['incomeBeforeTax'] = pd.to_numeric(inc_stmt['incomeBeforeTax'], downcast="float")

inc_stmt['nopat'] = inc_stmt['operatingIncome'] * (1 - inc_stmt['incomeTaxExpense'] /  inc_stmt['incomeBeforeTax'])
inc_stmt['nopat'] = pd.to_numeric(inc_stmt['nopat'])


## Balance sheet 
# "interestAndDebtExpense" ? "currentDebt" ?
# "totalAssets" - "totalLiabilities"

bs = pd.json_normalize(data_balance_sheet['annualReports'])
# bs['equity'] = pd.to_numeric(bs['totalAssets']) - pd.to_numeric(bs['totalLiabilities'])
bs['equity'] = pd.to_numeric(bs['totalShareholderEquity'])
bs.replace('None', '0', inplace=True)
bs['currentDebt'] = pd.to_numeric(bs['currentDebt'])


df = pd.merge(bs, inc_stmt, on='fiscalDateEnding')
df['returnOnCapitalInvested'] = df['nopat'] / (df['equity'] - df['currentDebt'])
```

#### Help

So how far are my calculations from the reality? I tried different formulas found around the web, but given my lack of financial experience, I can't match them perfectly on the values I get from Alpha Vantage.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm in the same boat basically, having tried different formula, but I can't get reliably close.

Comment: No, sorry. I consoled myself that this is a relative number and I can take some decisions based on it, regardless of the minor variations.

Comment: Same boat - would be nice to  be available  in AV api.